# Simultaneous iteration of Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

Given a Matrix $A$ we can use Simultaneous iteration(Using power iteration on all columns simultaneously) to compute the d biggest eigenvalues. Now this method will give you the biggest eigenvalues, but how can u find the smallest eigenvalues? Maybe by using it on the $A^{-1} $, or am i completely wrong?

Edit: So basically if you use simultaneous iteration on $A^{-1} $ you will find the biggest eigenvalues which then are the smallest eigenvalues of $A$

Comment: What kind of dimensions are you thinking about? Using the Hessenberg form, the usual SVD algorithms converge very rapidly towards the smallest eigenvalues. So the dimension has to be rather large, which then leads to the question if the matrix is sparse?

Comment: It is not too simple... You have to choose $n$ linear independent vectors $q_1$, $q_2$, ..., $q_n$ and iterate multiplying $A$ by them. Also, you have to use some technique to change the direction of these vector while you are iterating, otherwise, they will converge to the same vector, which should be the dominant eigenvector